# Loading a schema created using Visual Studio DataSet Designer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dataset

I have a simple DataSet with two DataTables which was designed using the VS10 DataSet designer, and I'm trying to read in it's schema file in order to initialize a dataSet I want to use in a WPF program. This is the code to initialize the DataSet:

```
    private DataSet currentMeasurement;

    private void CreateDataSource() { // initialize DataSet from schema
        currentMeasurement = new DataSet();
        currentMeasurement.ReadXmlSchema("MeasurementFile.xsd");
    }
```

where MeasurementFile.xsd is the file created by the DataSet designer.

However, VS is throwing the following error upon executing the ReadXmlSchema line:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: The invocation of the constructor on type 'MeasurementSet' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.

The CreateDataSource method is called from the MeasurementSet constructor, so the error information seems fairly useless to my eyes.

Why am I unable to read in the schema?